# Led grow lights

Tags: led, driver, boost

I need some advice regarding high powered LED chip and boost step up/down modules.

Firstly can a boost device be used with constant current drivers to reduce forward current to chip?

I have a 72w LED chip @ 26-31v @ 2.0A, I also have a driver 80w @ 30-36v @ 2.4A, I wish to reduce current to around 2.2A so is it possible for me to do this?

This is [the boost convertor](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-DC-600W-Boost-Converter-Step-up-Module-Power-Supply-10-60V-to-12-80V-/310800070913?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item485d20b901) and this is [the driver](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/80W-Warm-White-High-Power-5400L-LED-Light-AC-Driver-sxdc-/331037721347).

Another thing how do i know what the current level is when adjusting via potentiometer?

Some boost devices have a digital display to show voltage/current when stepping down or up, how will I know exactly what the outputs are when I reduce or increase them?

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Cross-posted and closed](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/35963/22) on [diy.se]

Comment: [Cross posted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145940/using-high-powered-led-with-cc-drivers-and-boost-step-up-down) on LaTeX too (interesting choice)

Comment: Links to ebay auctions probably aren't great as they will eventually expire.  You might benefit from reading [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings).

Answer (score 1):

> **Firstly can a boost device be used with constant current drivers to reduce forward current to chip?**

That's not what a voltage-booster is designed for, so no.

> **how do i know what the current level is when adjusting via potentiometer?**

I would use a multimeter (assuming that's a preset)

> **Some boost devices have a digital display to show voltage/current when stepping down or up, how will I know exactly what the outputs are when I reduce or increase them?**

By looking at the digital display? If the boost converter lacks this, I'd use a multimeter. If I intended doing this after initial setup, I'd consider adding panel meters to the circuit.